# Is there a reliable Art-Net library for Android (DMX over IP)?

Tags: java, android, dmx512

I am trying to find out the best if any available for controlling ArtNet enabled stage lighting devices using Android using the ArtNet protocol.

I came across [artnet4j](http://code.google.com/p/artnet4j/) but I am not sure if anyone has used it for the same purpose before. Please let me know if any has some hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library i have got to work with Android is [artnet4j](http://code.google.com/p/artnet4j/). It is a java based library and does the job it is suppose to do.

Answer (score 2):

For people in 2018 and later:

The initial release of [artnet4j](http://code.google.com/p/artnet4j/) has a lot of bugs and unimplemented methods, which won't be fixed, because the project is not under development anymore. I am working on a project that is tackling all these issues (based on the original artnet4j code). Currently supported is:

- Bind server to a custom network interface
- Reuse of the socket address
- Added ability to receive OpDmx packages
- Send and receive via UDP broadcast.
- Support for Art-Ext packages.

https://github.com/cansik/artnet4j

Answer (score -2):

I advice you a great programm 
lighting console lite or pro
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lightingconsolepro.lightingsoftware&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImxpZ2h0aW5nY29uc29sZXByby5saWdodGluZ3NvZnR3YXJlIl0.

Comment: This is an android application, not a library you'd use in a project!

Answer (score -3):

Try [Lighting Console Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=artnetconsole.artnet&hl=en) or Pro.

According to the documentation, it allows you to send DMX over ARTNET

Comment: This is an android application, not a library you'd use in a project!